# Error on the first convolution layer at the point of plus biases

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm stuck on the error regarding CNN.

Trying to implement the following structure on tensorflow.

[image]

I wrote my code as the tutorial ([Deep MNIST for Experts](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/tutorials/mnist/pros/index.html)) shows.Defined weight and bias initialization as below.

```
def weight_variable(shape):
    initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1)
    return tf.Variable(initial)


def bias_variable(shape):
    initial = tf.constant(0.1, shape=shape)
    return tf.Variable(initial)


def conv2d(x, W):
    return tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
```

And first convolution layer as following. Almost the same as Tutorial.

```
with tf.name_scope('conv1') as scope:
  W_conv1 = weight_variable([4, 1, 128, 256])
  b_conv1 = bias_variable([256])

  x_image = tf.reshape(images_placeholder, [-1,599,1,128])

  print tf.Tensor.get_shape(x_image)
  print tf.Tensor.get_shape(conv2d(x_image, W_conv1))

  h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x_image, W_conv1) + b_conv1)
```

However, I got error as following. How to solve this error?

```
  File "CNN_model.py", line 43, in inference
    h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x_image, W_conv1) + b_conv1)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py", line 403, in binary_op_wrapper
    return func(x, y, name=name)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_math_ops.py", line 44, in add
    return _op_def_lib.apply_op("Add", x=x, y=y, name=name)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/op_def_library.py", line 297, in apply_op
    g = ops._get_graph_from_inputs(_Flatten(keywords.values()), graph=g)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2879, in _get_graph_from_inputs
    assert_same_graph([original_input, op_input])
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 698, in assert_same_graph
    raise ValueError("Items must be from the same graph.")
  ValueError: Items must be from the same graph.
```

Answer (score 0):

That error is not from the code you showed. It looks like you are creating multiple graphs (maybe because of repeated invocations of an ipython notebook cell?) in  and try to use things from different graphs in the same computation.

Comment: how can I tell which thing is from which graph? Is there a code to show that?